# Procedure to write questions

Tags: exercises

I want to write a LaTeX file in which a question appears after compilation as  **Question 1**  if i write `\begin{Question} \end{Question}`

But then i would like to write answer for that and in that case i do not want the result after compilation to be **Solution 1** but as just solution...

Please suggest something for this...

EDIT :

I tried

```
\begin{Question}

XY**

\end{Question}
```

after compiling I am getting the outcome as

**Question 1 : XY****

But then i would like to write answer for this..

If i include the

Solution

the output, after compiling, in PDF file is not in exactly below the question but it is a bit right of the page..

Something like

> Question 1 : XY
>
> gap here Solution

Comment: Please can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have tried with a sample question and solution.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot : I tried to make it better... please have a look at this..

Comment: I suppose the ‘bit right of the page’  is paragraph indentation. Write `\noindent Solution`. Or better: make `Question` a theorem-like (numbered) environment  and `Solution` a proof-like environment.

Comment: @Bernard : Thank you... :) \nonindent Solution is working... I do not understand your second suggestion...Question a theorem-like (numbered) environment and Solution a proof-like environment.

Comment: You know there are dedicated packages and classes for this kind of thing like [`probsoln`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/probsoln), [`answers`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/answers), [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) or [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam), do you?

Comment: Well, *semantically*  questions look like  statements of theorems, and solutions like their proofs. It would have the advantage of automatic numbering, cross-referencing and layout (vertical spacing, choice of fonts, &c.)

Comment: @Bernard : Oh... fine fine... for time being \nonindent is working.. i would try what you have said...

Comment: @cgnieder : Oh... I did not know that...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik there are packages for almost anything :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcounter{Question}
\setcounter{Question}{1}

\newenvironment{question}[1]{\textbf{Question~\theQuestion~:}~#1\\}{}
```

you can use the new environment like this

```
\begin{question}{Who is the creator of \TeX}
  Donald Knuth
\end{question}
```

Comment: His name is *Knuth* :) (and of course he didn't invent *La*TeX ;)

Comment: @alexies : Thank you... at this time i can not see what would be the result after compiling this.. could you please post that too....